# What will I see if I travelled to a distant planet in 100 times faster than speed of light and look back?

Tags: faster-than-light, rocket-science

Consider this scenario. I enter a space ship at 10:00 AM, it starts to move at a speed **100 times** faster than  light, I travel for 55 mins. And then slow down to very much less than speed of light and land on another planet at 11:00 AM. Now I look at Earth with a telescope. What period of **Time** am I going to see?

Comment: You cannot travel faster than the speed of light. Also "at X:YY am" is ill-defined in relativity.

Comment: I know we cannot travel faster than light. But consider this as a theoretical question. And by AM I mean the time of earth.

Comment: Sreeraj M, if you presume that SR is false (which you must do if you allow for faster than light travel), what theoretical framework would you like us to use to answer this question?

Comment: I suggest he uses the Alcubierre drive framework. Then, after all the arguing about negative mass he gets to ask the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make it 10 minutes of travel, because I'm lazy. At 100x light speed you travel 1000 light minutes from Earth, so looking at earth you see images from 10:10 minus 1000 minutes which is 10:10 minus 16.6 hours. Which I am also too lazy to work out, but you get the idea?

Comment: What are you trying to answer?

Comment: What he would see looking backwards towards Earth using a telescope. I thought that was obvious from the question.