# Telescopes and faster than light travel

Tags: visible-light, faster-than-light, telescopes

If sometime in the future we master faster than light travel,  could we solve past crimes by warping to a place in space where the light from Earth is just arriving from that time period and using a powerful telescope?

Comment: what do you mean by warping to a place in space?

Comment: Why not use a simple video camera for this purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will I see if I travelled to a distant planet in 100 times faster than speed of light and look back?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147413/)

Comment: If there's a "mirror planet" anywhere in space, we can do better than this, and just watch our own history reflected back at us, at least in theory. Realistically, we have nowhere near that kind of telescopic resolution.